# Deleting the same filename in various subdirectories

Tags: python, automation

Is there a way for python to go into the subdirectory and the second subdirectory of a folder and delete a certain file? I have 1 directory and in it 20 other subdirectory and each of those have their own subdirectories with a certain file I want deleted. I know I can hardcode the path of each one but is there an easier way?

```
import os, glob
for filename in glob.glob("C:\sshconnect.py"):
    os.remove(filename)
```

EDIT:  I want it so lets say I have `"C:\Stackoverflow\sshconnect.py"` &`"C:\Testing\Test1\sshconnect.py"` & `"C:\Test2\sshconnect.py"`, it should go through all those and delete `sshconnect.py` in all folders.

Comment: `for filename in glob.glob(r"C:\*\sshconnect.py"):` will delete the .py file in all `C:` direct subdirs (not recursive). Is that what you want?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I want it so lets say I have "C:\Stackoverflow\sshconnect.py"  &"C:\Testing\Test1\sshconnect.py"  & "C:\Test2\sshconnect.py"    it will go through all those and delete the sshconnect.py

Comment: understood. Next time [edit] your question instead of commenting. I've done that for you so you see how it could be phrased better.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sorry about that

Comment: not an issue. Now you know. The aim is that the question is clear for future readers. Comments are just temporary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there: `glob` returns a list of the expanded filepaths. Just iterate on them and remove the files.

Since you have 2 levels of files, you could do this:

```
import os, glob
for filename in glob.glob(r"C:\*\sshconnect.py")+glob.glob(r"C:\*\*\sshconnect.py"):
    try:
        os.remove(filename) 
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print(str(e))
```

(note the exception handling in case a file is protected: script continues)

or this if you want any depth:

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(r"C:\\"):
   for f in files:
       if f=="sshconnect.py":
          try:
             os.remove(os.path.join(root,f))
          except FileNotFoundError as e:
             print(str(e))
```

For legacy versions of python like 2.5, write `except FileNotFoundError, e:`

Comment: Getting an error "invalid syntax  except FileNotFoundError as e:" did you mean "in e"?

Comment: you seem to use a very old version of python... Is it 2.5? you could try `except FileNotFoundError, e:` then. But I suggest that you upgrade instead (to python 3 for instance)

Comment: Yea it was 2.5, If you dont mind me asking what is the "os.walk(r) for? Specifically the r

Comment: r is for raw prefix. Avoids doubling the backslashes. Well, not here since it's the last backslash. But good practice. And os.walk is recursive file/directory scanning.